# Getting an error while Executing RAISE error Dynamically

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I want to execute the RAISE error based on the SELECT statement.
I am sure that will work or not. If possible can someone help with the below code

```
DECLARE
A ExcEPTION;
V_T VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
SELECT ' RAISE A ' INTO V_T FROM DUAL;
EXECUTE  IMMEDIATE V_T;
EXCEPTION
WHEN A THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ABC');
END ;
```

Answer (score 3):

It'll work, but not as you wanted (I guess). You'll have to dynamically execute the whole PL/SQL block that contains exception declaration and its handling section. Something like this:

```
SQL> declare
  2    v_t varchar2(1000);
  3  begin
  4    select ' RAISE A ' into v_t from dual;
  5    execute  immediate
  6      'declare a exception; begin ' || v_t ||
  7      '; exception when a then dbms_output.put_line(''abc''); end;';
  8  end ;
  9  /
abc

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```